# read QTableview selected row QSQLITE database

Tags: qt, qtsql

I show the data of a table (table1) in a QTableView. When the user selects a row, I want to read the data from this highlighted line. How can I do it easily?

For example will this read the whole data?

```
query.exec("SELECT * table1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a [`QSqlTableModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QSqlTableModel.html) with your view. In this case you can use [`currentIndex`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#currentIndex) in order to get the model index of the current item and then use the [`record`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquerymodel.html#record) function of the `QSqlTableModel` in order to get the record corresponding to the index's row:

```
QModelIndex curIndex = tableView->currentIndex();
QSqlRecord record = model->record(curIndex.row());
```

Then you can use the [`field`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlrecord.html#field) function of `QSqlRecord` in order to get the values at the columns you want.